# Could not execute Rust linker for armv7-linux-android target

Tags: android, dll, compiler-errors, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to compile a Rust project into a `*.so` lib for arm.

Cargo.toml:

```toml
[package]
name = "light_processor"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.51"
sync = "0.1.0"
enum-primitive-derive = "0.1.2"
num-traits = "0.2.6"

[lib]
name = "NativePluginRust"
crate-type = ["dylib"]

[target.'cfg(target_os="android")'.dependencies]
jni = { version = "0.5", default-features = false }
```

.cargo/config

```toml
[target.x86_64-linux-android]
ar = "C:\\NDK\\x86\\bin\\x86_64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "C:\\NDK\\x86_64\\bin\\x86_64-linux-android-clang++"

[target.aarch64-linux-android]
ar = "C:\\NDK\\arm64\\bin\\aarch64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "C:\\NDK\\arm64\\bin\\aarch64-linux-android-clang++"

[target.armv7-linux-androideabi]
ar = "C:\\NDK\\arm\\bin\\arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
linker = "C:\\NDK\\arm\\bin\\arm-linux-androideabi-clang++"

[target.i686-linux-android]
ar = "C:\\NDK\\x86\\bin\\i686-linux-android-ar"
linker = "C:\\NDK\\x86\\bin\\i686-linux-android-clang++"
```

Platform and other

```
Cargo/rustc version: cargo 1.35.0-nightly (0e35bd8af 2019-03-13)
Windows 10
NDK - r19c
```

When I run `cargo build --target armv7-linux-androideabi --release`, I get this compile error:

```
error: could not exec the linker
`C:\NDK\arm\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-clang++`

= note: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. (os error 193)
= note: "C:\\NDK\\arm\\bin\\arm-linux-androideabi-clang++" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition" "-march=armv7-a" "-L"
"C:\\Users\\User\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\lib"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.0.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.1.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.10.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.11.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.12.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.13.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.14.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.2.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.3.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.4.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.5.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.6.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.7.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.8.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.NativePluginRust.aeolmuqr-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "-o" "C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\libNativePluginRust.so"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.2sbup2a6qpfbk1uq.rcgu.o"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps\\NativePluginRust.j6dacp3pd956ibr.rcgu.o" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L"
"C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\release\\deps" "-L" "C:\\other\\light_processor\\target\\release\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\User\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\armv7-linux-androideabi\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\liblibc-dcfb7bb75e1bfeb5.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\libnum_traits-be8894f2a1f013ae.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\libstd-97937ccdc225868f.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\libpanic_unwind-527aca3d5ee99993.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\libbacktrace_sys-a0c445accc9b96e3.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\librustc_demangle-c3cf34e8879986a1.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\libunwind-0b9df9c0d003ddcb.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\liblibc-26698ce62cc62b28.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\liballoc-d934247b7fc04a98.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\librustc_std_workspace_core-beae7b27ff1a115e.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--whole-archive"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\libcore-449b58af4aafb370.rlib" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--end-group"
"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7zLh6u\\libcompiler_builtins-24a897e39347c695.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ldl" "-llog" "-lgcc" "-lc" "-lm" "-shared"
```

[image: Screenshot linker directory]

What is the problem behind this error?

Comment: *"error: could not exec the linker `C:\NDK\arm\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-clang++`"* Please verify that the path is correct and a executable by your OS (e.g. not an ELF that is not runable by Windows or vice versa).

Comment: You haven't answered my question yet. Can you execute the file (in a cmd) or not?

Comment: linker file or what ?

Comment: Yes. That file that the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: C:\NDK\arm\bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: C:\\NDK\\arm\\bin\\arm-linux-androideabi-clang++:2:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
C:\NDK\arm\bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: C:\\NDK\\arm\\bin\\arm-linux-androideabi-clang++: not an object or archive

Comment: C:\NDK\arm\bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/28\crtbegin_dynamic.o:crtbegin.c:function _start_main: error: undefined reference to 'main'
clang80++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: It's hard to help you, because you are not really giving good information here. What is that output you just posted? Did you execute the file? What happened? Also your screenshot only shows the files without a file extension (which is always bad on windows, time that they change that!). The compiler wants to execute `C:\NDK\arm\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-clang++`, not the `.bat` file. Are you sure it's a windows executeable? Have you ever used that toolchain successfully?

Comment: I just used this and same articles [link](https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-21-rust-on-android.html) to setup toolchain's

Comment: arm-linux-androideabi-clang code:
@echo off
setlocal
call :find_bin
if "%1" == "-cc1" goto :L


set "_BIN_DIR=" && %_BIN_DIR%clang80.exe -target armv7a-linux-androideabi28 -fno-addrsig %*
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit /b 1
goto :done

:L
rem target/triple already spelled out.
set "_BIN_DIR=" && %_BIN_DIR%clang80.exe %*
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit /b 1
goto :done

:find_bin
rem Accommodate a quoted arg0, e.g.: "clang"
rem https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/616
set _BIN_DIR=%~dp0
exit /b

:done

Comment: The article looks like a mac tutorial for me. And so I suggest that the toolchain is for mac. If have no clue though.

Comment: It's not important
Now we don't need to generate toolchain, just use $NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi26-clang++

Comment: But it's not make me happy :(